# Solr check and exclude result if it falls within a date range

Tags: date, datetime, elasticsearch, solr, date-range

So, I have entities which are being indexed. These entities can be booked, and thus have a series of bookings with start and end dates.

Eg:

```
[ {start:"2016-01-20", end:"2016-01-22"}, {start:"2016-01-30", end:"2016-02-10"}
```

And so on. Now, I want to filter these results by a *single* date range selected by users. Say they are looking for all results available from 2016-01-25 to 2016-01-28. How would I exclude individual results if *any* of their start/end combinations falls within/overlaps the single query range?